# How can we access the Child Key from Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to loop my child array but it's not working. It's working fine which it's first items but not working on the child elements.

```json
"candidateApplication": [
    {
        "label": "Are you currently attending school?",
        "id": "ap_currentschool",
        "value": "",
        "required": "N",
        "type": "radio",
        "display": null,
        "list": [
            {
                "searchCode": "yes",
                "searchValue": "yes"
            },
            {
                "searchCode": "no",
                "searchValue": "no"
            }
        ],
        "onSelect": [
            {
                "yes": [
                    {
                        "label": "Estimated Completion Date",
                        "id": "ap_compdate",
                        "value": "",
                        "required": "N",
                        "type": "date",
                        "display": null,
                        "list": null,
                        "onSelect": null
                    }
                ],
                "no": null
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

I am easily access my data to looping lists like obj.candidateApplication.list But I am not able to loop through obj.candidateApplication.onSelect.yes.

Can anybody please guide me how can I fix that issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpKfC.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: JSON is a text format. By the time you're doing things like `obj.candidateApplication`, it's an object, not JSON.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: `obj.candidateApplication` is an array (`[...]`) so you need to use an index to get the object you want under it (e.g., `obj.candidateApplication[0].list` or `obj.candidateApplication[0].onSelect[0].yes`), or iterate over `obj.candidateApplication`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing `obj.candidateApplication.onSelect.yes` which is `undefined` because `obj.candidateApplication.onSelect` is an array of objects.

You probably want to loop over `obj.candidateApplication.onSelect` and then for each object you can access the `yes` property as you wish:

```js
$.each(onSelect, function (index, element) {
    $.each(element.yes, function (x, y) {
        // your code here
    })
});
```

Edit: As pointed by [Heritic Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey) in the comments, `obj.candidateApplication` is an array as well, but in the picture attached to the question, there's already a local variable called `onSelect`, loop through that instead of `obj.candidateApplication.onSelect` because it's `undefined`. (at least it should be, we don't know what your code is doing)

Comment: `obj.candidateApplication` is an array as well. This is all covered in the linked question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thankyou For Deeply guide it. I really appreciate it

Comment: @HereticMonkey I edited the answer to showcase that problem.

Comment: @soufianeyakoubi Actually I am getting the data from the API and then based on the generating the Form fields.